# Failed to load module script when creating new React app

Tags: reactjs

I use "npx create-react-app my-app" to create new project. Previously in worked fine. But now page doesn't load and I have error in console

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script 
but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I get this error in chrome and opera. In edge everyting works. How to fix? I have default React starter. Didn't change the code.